# translate java 2d array into ruby

Tags: ruby

How would I write this java code into ruby:

```
String[] [] Score = new String [row] [col];
Score[rCount][cCount] = num;
```

I thought it would as simple as:

```
score=[]
score[rcount][ccount]=num
```

But I keep getting "undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then ask. People over here are trying to help you. The least you could do is format the question so that its more readable. Why do you need java tag ?

Comment: You could improve your question by removing the reference to Java. Just ask, for example, how you could create an array `arr` that permits `arr[row][col] = 3` to set a value and `arr[row][col]` to return a value.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I don't know java, but have a look at the class methods [Array#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and [Array::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D), and the instance methods [Array#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and [Array#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D). Here are some examples that should answer your question (and other questions that may be sparked, hopefully):

```
Array.new #=> [] 
[]        #=> [] # shorthand for above

a = Array.new(5) { [] } #=> [[], [], [], [], []] 

a[0][0] = 2
a #=> [[2], [], [], [], []] 
a[3][2] = 4
a #=> [[2], [], [], [nil, nil, 4], []] 
a[1] << 1
a #=> [[2], [1], [], [nil, nil, 4], []] 
a[1] << 2
a #=> [[2], [1, 2], [], [nil, nil, 4], []] 
a[1] << 3 << 4
a #=> [[2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [], [nil, nil, 4], []] 
a[2] << [4,5]
a #=> [[2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [[4, 5]], [nil, nil, 4], []] 
a[4].concat([4,5]) 
a #=> [[2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [[4, 5]], [nil, nil, 4], [4, 5]] 

a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]] 
a[1][2] = 4 
a #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, 4], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

We could also write the default as a second argument:

```
a = Array.new(3,[]) #=> [[], [], []]
```

but that can be problematic:

```
a[0][0] = 'cat'
a #=> [["cat"], ["cat"], ["cat"]]
```

as is:

```
a = Array.new(3,Array.new(2)) #=> [[], [], []]
  #=> [[nil, nil], [nil, nil], [nil, nil]] 
a[0][0] = 'cat'
a #=> [["cat", nil], ["cat", nil], ["cat", nil]]
```

since each element of `a` is the same array.

Note that Ruby provides a convenience for writing certain methods that is commonly referred to as "[syntactic sugar](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_syntactic_sugar.html)". If, for example, you write `a = [1,2,3]`, Ruby will interpret that as `a = Array.[](1,2,3)` (and you could write it that way), the class method being [Array::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D). Similarly, if `a` equals `[1,2,3]`, `a[1] = 'cat'` is decoded as `a.[]=(1, 'cat')` and `a[1] #=> 'cat'` is `a.[](1)`. Similarly, `h = {}` translates to `h = Hash.new` and so on.

Note that Ruby does not have a concept of "multidimensional arrays". For more on that you may wish to see a comment a left on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901706/multidimestional-array-initialize-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-0#comment55566748_33901706).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ruby programmers use snake case. Capital letter is using for class names.

Secondly, your problem happens just because

```
score[rcount] == nil # true
```

If you want to have an access to second dimension elements you need to initialize line as array:

```
score[rcount] = []
```

Now you can set second dimension element

```
score[rcount][ccount] = num
```