# Multidimesional Array - `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, initialization

I'm still new in Ruby on Rails. Today I'm trying to write some codes which can run the the following:

```
image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])

image.output_image
```

And I'm having trouble setup the initialize. My codes is as below, can someone help me?
Thanks a lot

```
class Subary
    attr_accessor :num1, :num2, :num3, :num4

    def initialize (num1, num2, num3, num4)
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        self.num3 = num3
        self.num4 = num4
    end

    def output_subary
        puts "#{num1}#{num2}#{num3}#{num4}"
    end

end

# subary = Subary.new(0,0,0,0)
# puts subary.output_subary

class Image
    def initialize 
        @subarys = []
        @subarys << Subary.new(:num1, :num2, :num3, :num4)
        @subarys << Subary.new(:num1, :num2, :num3, :num4)
        @subarys << Subary.new(:num1, :num2, :num3, :num4)
        @subarys << Subary.new(:num1, :num2, :num3, :num4)
    end

    def output_image
        @subarys.each do |list|
            list.output_subary
        end
    end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
image.output_image
```

Comment: Ruby does not have a concept of "multidimensional arrays". The term is used loosely to describe an array having a particular structure, but it can be confusing and is best to avoid. All arrays merely contain objects, which are normally referred to "elements". Your array `image` contains four elements, each of which is an array of four elements. Had it been what you might think of as a "three-dimensional" array, it might contain four elements that are arrays, each of which is an array of four elements that are themselves arrays of, say, three elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cary. Help me get more clear about the concept.

Comment: ..and this is a perfectly-good array: `[1, 3.1, "cat", :dog, 4..7, [5, {3=>{:a=>[4,5]}}]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

This error means that, `initialize` method does not take any argument (0), but you passed one argument to it. Change the `initialize` method's definition in your `Image` class. Then, it should work.

```
class Subary
    attr_accessor :num1, :num2, :num3, :num4

    def initialize(sub_array)
        self.num1 = sub_array[0]
        self.num2 = sub_array[1]
        self.num3 = sub_array[2]
        self.num4 = sub_array[3]
    end

    def output_subary
        puts "#{num1}#{num2}#{num3}#{num4}"
    end
end

# subary = Subary.new(0,0,0,0)
# puts subary.output_subary

class Image
    def initialize(array_of_arrays)
        @subarys = []
        @subarys << Subary.new(array_of_arrays[0])
        @subarys << Subary.new(array_of_arrays[1])
        @subarys << Subary.new(array_of_arrays[2])
        @subarys << Subary.new(array_of_arrays[3])
    end

    def output_image
        @subarys.each do |list|
            list.output_subary
        end
    end
end

image = Image.new([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
])
image.output_image
# => 0000
# => 0100
# => 0001
# => 0000
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I'm confused in what I could put inside the argument. As my final out put wann be:
0000
0100
0010
0000

which are four arrays.

Comment: ok, give me some time. I will update my answer to met your requirement.

Comment: Ken, the error message also gave the line where the exception was raised (`def initialize`). You need to get in the habit of studying error messages carefully. They contain valuable information, often pinpointing the problem, as here.

Comment: @KenSaluda, look at my updated answer please. That's a working version of the code with minimal changes to your existing code.

Comment: I changed the definition of the `initialize` methods for both your `Subary` and `Image` class and made the related code adjustments.

Comment: That's so cool!Thanks K M. I wasn't know that "array" could simply put inside the argument. I just took a lot of time figure our how it should be made to represent four arrays.

Comment: @KenSaluda great to know that it worked and solved your problem. You are welcome :)

Comment: Hi . @K M Rakibul Islam  Sorry. Can you explain more about the meaning of:
        subarys << Subary.new(array[0])
  
Thanks

Comment: ok, I will update my answer shortly to explain it a bit more. If you have any particular question, you can ask me here.

Comment: `array` is basically an array of arrays there which is the argument for the `initilize` method of `Image` class. `array[0]` is the first array from that array of arrays. You are creating a Subary instance here: `Subary.new(array[0])` and passing the first array as argument: `array[0]`

Comment: Thank you @KMRakibulIslam, that make sense for me now.